# php mysqli binding parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm assuming php is inserting single quotes around $id when binding the parameters which is causing my query to fail.  I know $id is the issue because when I manually put the string in the place of the first ? the query works.  Problem is that I need the query to work using the variable $id, any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

```
 if
($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) from friendships where ? = (select id from users where username = ?) and friendstatus = ?")) {

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $id, $username,$friendstatus);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
        }
```

Comment: Your SQL query is bad. That's not the right way to go about it in SQL.

Comment: `where ? = (select ...)`? why not just a join?

Comment: going to convert my subquery into a join for performance,  thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable column names are not possible with Prepared Statements. In general variable column names are not needed with well made queries. Consider using a join instead.